# how to distribute load in group of activemq brokers

Tags: activemq-classic

I am trying to find a way to load balance requests to a group of similar configuration activemq brokers.
Suppose, i have 3 activemq brokers(A, B, C), each having (say) two queues (X,Y) operating.

> Every activemq broker has same queues ie. X & Y.
> Every activemq broker queues have a dedicated consumer. which consumes messages only from their respective broker's queue.
>
> Now, I want to load balance requests to my 3 queues load balanced in round-robin. i.e. the 1st request should go to Queue A, then next request to queue B and then next request to queue C and so on.

Any guidance please.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ActiveMQ's Networks of Brokers feature:  http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html.  I'd use as much of ActiveMQ's built-in functionality as possible before coming up with any custom round-robin code of your own.